# How do I cache request-tracker4?

Tags: cache, request-tracker

I've been using request tracker v4.0.8, over a relatively high latency internet connection, and I noticed that many (all?) of the supposedly static resources  (css, javascript, images) are located in a `/NoAuth/` directory.

The CSS and javascript for each page are generated by RT on each request, and are served with `Cache-Control: no-cache`. The images and additional requests generated by those files (misc images, more css, etc) are also no-cache. This all seems rather wasteful, to me.

Is there some trick or configuration that I can use to make RT operate in a less cache-hostile way?

Answer (score 0):

As recommended in the [RT web deployment documentation](http://bestpractical.com/rt/docs/4.0/web_deployment.html), Apache should be configured with

```
Alias /NoAuth/images/ /opt/rt4/share/html/NoAuth/images/
```

The equivalent in nginx is

```
location /NoAuth/images {
    root /opt/rt4/share/html;
}
```

... and in lighttpd it is

```
alias.url = (
    "/NoAuth/images/" => "/opt/rt4/share/html/NoAuth/images/",
)
```

Comment: Yes, I've already done that. I suppose I should have mentioned that in my question. The problem is that there are a lot of resources that are either referenced by CSS or loaded dynamically via javascript, and they are not cached. Images don't seem to be my problem, it's apparently un-cacheable CSS and JS.